# Large JavaScript Modular App loading and un-loading libraries as needed?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a JavaScript with PHP Backend Media Manger Library.

Similar to WordPress media manger however there will be about 20 module/plugins for creating/adding new Media.

For example some of the modules:

- Extract Frames from an Animated GIF image and upload any of the Frames as a new Image in your media library.
- Scrape a webpage for images and upload any of the images to your media library.\
- Canvas based Image annotation editor
- Markdown File creator and reader
- Create animated GIF images using multiple images.
- CSS Sprite Image Generator
- QRCode Generator
- PDF File Viewer
- PSD File Viewer
- Upload from URL
- Drag & Drop Uploader
- Paste File Uploader
- Upload From Base64 String
- ...and several more....

### The Problem

Now obviously several of these modules will rely on using existing libraries.

In a users application where they are using my Media Manger library, I don't want to bog down the  users computer by loading tons of 3rd party JS libraries that all the modules rely on all at once.

### How to fix?

Is there a way to load and un-load libraries as they are needed?

My media manger lib will open up in an app as a popup modal.  If I was to open the media manger modal as an Iframe, when the modal is closed I could remove the Iframe from the DOM, would this free up all the resources that alll the JS libraries previously loaded had consumed in the browser?

---

[image]

Comment: Are you talking to implement lazy loading.. Only loading the content needed in current window. ?

Comment: @atulquest93 More about how to unload a library regardless of when it is loaded

Answer (score 0):

if you do something like `delete window.myLibrary` then it will delete any code or data present under the `myLibrary` object (because functions are objects too!), which will be garbage collected and removed. This of course assumes that the libraries you want to un-load are accessible in this way.